# Can't upload data from Raspbian to PHPMyAdmin server

Tags: raspbian, web-server, mysql, python-3

I am trying to upload data from Raspbian to my web server which is PHPMyAdmin MySQL type.

I am trying to do this using Python 3, as follows:

```py
import pymysql as ps
con = ps.connect(host='ip address of host', database='database_name', user='database_user',passwd='password')
c6s = con.cursor()
sqlcmd = """ INSERT INTO {} (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""".format('table_name')
c6s.execute(sqlcmd, (data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4]))
con6s.commit()
con6s.close()
print("%s uploaded on cloud " % (db))
```

The error code is 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2003 indicates that the remote host refused connection. Set up mysql to allow remote connections. This is typically done with the bind-adress directive in mysql config.

https://support.servergrove.com/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server/ contains some information.